# Getting all of the properties (Including the hidden ones) of 0 (The root object)

Tags: matlab

It seems that the root object, a.k.a `0` has hidden properties in Matlab. For example, `DefaultTextInterpreter`  is one of them:

```
 x = get(0,'DefaultTextInterpreter');
```

When I use

```
 get(0)
```

I get a long list, which **does not** include `DefaultTextInterpreter`.

---

Even setting [undocumented properties](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/getundoc-get-undocumented-object-properties/) to be visible by

```
 set(0,'HideUndocumented','off');
```

does not seem to help.

---

How can I find **all** of the properties of the root object, including `DefaultTextInterpreter`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default properties are not hidden nor undocumented - they are available for all standard Handle Graphics properties by simply prefixing 'Default' to the property name, together with the object type ('Line', 'Axes' etc.). This is explained in [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-21465.html).

In fact, this mechanism also works for hidden/undocumented properties, as [shown](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-linesmoothing-property/#comment-8807) for the LineSmoothing property.

To see all the supported default properties, do as follows:

```
>> get(0,'Default')
ans = 
          defaultFigurePosition: [440 378 560 420]
               defaultTextColor: [0 0 0]
              defaultAxesXColor: [0 0 0]
              defaultAxesYColor: [0 0 0]
              defaultAxesZColor: [0 0 0]
          defaultPatchFaceColor: [0 0 0]
          defaultPatchEdgeColor: [0 0 0]
               defaultLineColor: [0 0 0]
    defaultFigureInvertHardcopy: 'on'
             defaultFigureColor: [0.8 0.8 0.8]
               defaultAxesColor: [1 1 1]
          defaultAxesColorOrder: [7x3 double]
          defaultFigureColormap: [64x3 double]
        defaultSurfaceEdgeColor: [0 0 0]
         defaultFigurePaperType: 'A4'
        defaultFigurePaperUnits: 'centimeters'
         defaultFigurePaperSize: [20.98404194812 29.67743169791]
```

Note that this does not return the undocumented defaults. You can always get the undocumented defaults directly:

```
>> get(0,'DefaultLineLineSmoothing')
ans =
off
```

---

Since I can't help myself :-), here's a bit of now-really-undocumented knowledge, which does not answer the OP question but it somehow related. Readers who are only interested in the original question or in purely-documented/supported stuff can safely skip this part:

```
>> p = findprop(handle(gcf),'pos')
p =
    schema.prop

>> p.get
            Name: 'Position'
     Description: ''
        DataType: 'figurePositionType'
    FactoryValue: [100 100 660 520]
     AccessFlags: [1x1 struct]
         Visible: 'on'
     GetFunction: []
     SetFunction: []
```

In this simple snippet, note that the default (FactoryValue) for the position property of the UDD hg.Figure class is different than the HG default that is returned by the root's DefaultFigurePosition property. More information on UDD properties can be found [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/udd-properties/).

**Addendum 2013-02-13**: I've just posted a [detailed article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/getting-default-hg-property-values/) explaining how Matlab's Default and Factory property values work, how they relate to each other, and how they can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So basically I need to do `get(0,'Default')` to see all of them. Can you please add this fact to your answer, for other people?

Comment: How I could miss it? I even was on that page! Great answer, @Yair, as usual. The only correction: it's not simply prefixing 'Default', but also adding the object type - 'Line', 'Axes', etc. I'm also curious how this mechanism is different from getting standard HG properties.

Answer (score 2):

0 is call [Root object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rootobject.html). ([Setting Default Property Values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-21465.html))

This not a full answer to the question. I just want to get your attention to couple of articles at [UndocumentedMatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/):

- [Displaying hidden handle properties](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/displaying-hidden-handle-properties/)
- [getundoc – get undocumented object properties](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/getundoc-get-undocumented-object-properties/)

It has a link to great utility from Yair Altman - [getundoc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32934-getundoc-get-undocumented-object-properties). However it also does not show the default properties.

I believe [@Yair_Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman) is the one who should answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found that link, and even wrote in my question about set(0,'HideUndocumented','off'); But it does not seem to help with 'DefaultTextInterpreter'

Comment: Yes, I thought you aware about the article. But since the link was not in the question, I put it here.

Comment: Well, anyhow, (+1) , since the answer might help someone else