# Default Property Values for Plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, default, matlab-figure

I try to set default values to some properties I am using in my MATLAB script.
For example:

```
set(0,'defaultAxesMarkerSize', 3);
```

This doesnt work, because Axes doesnt have the property MarkerSize.

 But how is it possible to set the default properties of all plots like:

```
stem(...);
```

Comment: Might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268496/getting-all-of-the-properties-including-the-hidden-ones-of-0-the-root-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the default properties of graphics objects, the usual format is as follows:

1- `default`

2- `type of object`

3-`property`

4-`value of that property`.

Or as stated on the Mathworks website (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html)):

> 'default' ObjectType PropertyName

Therefore, since `MarkerSize` is a property of line objects (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html) for all of them), you would need to replace `Axes` in your code above with `Line`:

```
set(0,'DefaultLineMarkerSize',3);
```

Small example:

```
clear
clc
close all

set(0,'DefaultLineMarkerSize',3); %// The default is usually 6

X = linspace(0,2*pi,50)';
Y = [cos(X), 0.5*sin(X)];

stem(X,Y(:,1))
hold on
set(0,'DefaultLineMarkerSize',10);
stem(X,Y(:,2),'--r')

set(gca,'XLim',[0 X(end)])
```

Producing the following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, The documentation of MATLAB is very bad at this section I think.
They should take your example